# Excel formula for trend?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

does any one can suggest me any formula in excel to use for following question.
I have a data list with historical numbers for each particular example. I would need in column G Categoraise in 3 Categories Increasing, Decreasing, Various:
For exmaple

```
Column A    Column B  Column C  Column D  Column E    Column F  Column G
            month 1   month2    month3      month4    month5    Category
Example 1   3           1         2          0           4       Various
Example 2   6           4         3          1           0       Decreasing 
Example 3   0           0         3          5           10       Increasing
```

I am not sure that trend focmula is a correct one.
Any kind suggestion?

Comment: Will you always just have 6 columns?

Comment: How is example 3 "Increasing"? 5 isn't less than 1. Your categories are not clear.

Comment: Hi, Jepp, only those 6 columns. Data in columns B to F can vary. i.e. each example may have different numbers, but sum of overwhelming tendency for these columns B to F  decreasing, increasing och varying is there despite numbers. Can easely be obious for a human eye. But not possible to perform categorisation manually, if dataset is from 5000 rows and upwards. So I was trying to figure out if there might be some clever formula.

Comment: @John Coleman: Sorry about example 3 Increasing Column F should be 10 not 1. I have corrected it now.

Comment: What if the row is all `0`?

Answer (score 4):

Use nested IFS with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:E2<C2:F2)),SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:E2>C2:F2))),"Various",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:E2<C2:F2)),"increasing",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:E2>C2:F2)),"decreasing","even")))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I almost never have the patience (or the formula jujitsu) to puzzle out a formula-approach once I see a VBA solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a VBA solution which can be used directly on the worksheet:

```
Function ClassifySequence(nums As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long, minDelta As Long, maxDelta As Long
    Dim delta As Variant
    
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        maxDelta = .Min(nums) - .Max(nums)
        minDelta = -maxDelta
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To nums.Cells.Count - 1
        delta = nums.Cells(i + 1).Value - nums.Cells(i).Value
        If delta < minDelta Then minDelta = delta
        If delta > maxDelta Then maxDelta = delta
    Next i
    
    If maxDelta <= 0 Then
        ClassifySequence = "Decreasing"
    ElseIf minDelta >= 0 Then
        ClassifySequence = "Increasing"
    Else
        ClassifySequence = "Various"
    End If
End Function
```

For example,

[image]

In this code I decided to classify a constant sequence as decreasing. That could of course be changed, either to "Various" or "Increasing" or by creating a fourth category as in Scott Craner's excellent answer.

Comment: Hi Scott and John, Thank you so much for you kind advices. Both solutions work. :-)

Comment: @lika consider marking one as accepted. I recommend that you accept Scott's since it answers your question more directly.